# Android development, using Exoplayer to make a player,then Encounter an error

Tags: android

```
DefaultDataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSource.Factory(MainActivity.this, Util.getUserAgent(MainActivity.this, "Work2"));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUVCU.png)
Please help me!!Thanks for all helper!

```
DefaultDataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSource.Factory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "Work2"));
```

I try to be like this, the mistake is still there.

Answer (score 1):

DefaultDataSource.Factory no longer needs the user agent string. Just use:

```
DefaultDataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSource.Factory(this);
```